# $v$ is continuous and $f$ is continuously differentiable. Is $v \cdot \nabla f$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

The full question:

Let $v: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Is $v \cdot \nabla f$ continuous?

My attempt:

It seems like it follows trivially from the definition... $f$ being continuously differentiable means $\nabla f$ is continuous, so its components are all continuous; $v$ is continuous, so its components are continuous as well. Hence $v \cdot \nabla f = \sum_{j=1}^n v_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ is a sum of products of continuous functions, which is continuous. I feel like I must be missing something here.

Comment: Looks fine for me. Why do you think you are missing something?

Comment: I got this from a previous University of British Columbia qualifying exam, where the questions tend to be pretty difficult. It just seemed too easy, I guess.

Comment: I think you have it.